# How to find correlation between two integer arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, math, int, correlation

I am searching a lot but could not find exactly what i need till now.
I have two integer arrayas `int[] x` and `int[] y`. I want to find simple *linear correlation* between these two integer arrays and it should return the result as `double`. In java do you know any library function providing this or any code snippet?

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing in core Java. There are libraries out there you can use. Apache Commons has a [statistical project](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html), check [PearsonCorrelation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/correlation/PearsonsCorrelation.html) class.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] x = {1, 2, 4, 8};
    double[] y = {2, 4, 8, 16};
    double corr = new PearsonsCorrelation().correlation(y, x);

    System.out.println(corr);
}
```

prints out 1.0

Answer (score 11):

Correlation is quite *easy to compute* manually:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence

```
  public static double Correlation(int[] xs, int[] ys) {
    //TODO: check here that arrays are not null, of the same length etc

    double sx = 0.0;
    double sy = 0.0;
    double sxx = 0.0;
    double syy = 0.0;
    double sxy = 0.0;

    int n = xs.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      double x = xs[i];
      double y = ys[i];

      sx += x;
      sy += y;
      sxx += x * x;
      syy += y * y;
      sxy += x * y;
    }

    // covariation
    double cov = sxy / n - sx * sy / n / n;
    // standard error of x
    double sigmax = Math.sqrt(sxx / n -  sx * sx / n / n);
    // standard error of y
    double sigmay = Math.sqrt(syy / n -  sy * sy / n / n);

    // correlation is just a normalized covariation
    return cov / sigmax / sigmay;
  }
```

Comment: @Mvorisek: it can be either `i++` or `++i`; `++i` can be a bit faster (no need to return pervious state) on the old time compilers. Just a habbit from Intel 8086 times and `C` compilers for them...

Comment: This doesn't cover the case were xs and ys have different length.

Comment: @htellez: correlation (or even covariation) wants equal lengths, or one should extend the standard correlation's definition.